# How to Simulate a 404 Not Found Api endpoint with EmberJs Mirage

Tags: ember.js

In config.js of Mirage. For example:

```
this.get('path/to/endpoint', (schema, request) => {
  return '404';
});
```

How should the returned response be formatted so that Mirage treats it like a real 404?

Answer (score 3):

```
import Response from 'ember-cli-mirage/response';

this.get('path/to/endpoint', (schema, request) => {
  return new Response(404);
});
```

Found [here](http://www.ember-cli-mirage.com/docs/v0.4.x/route-handlers/). For me `new Mirage.Response` worked too.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return a "non-standard" status with mirage, add the response to the end of the verb.

```
this.get('path/to/endpoint', undefined, 404);
//OR
this.get('path/to/endpoint', {message:'Nothing found'}, 404);
```

See the [route documentation for mirage](http://www.ember-cli-mirage.com/docs/v0.1.x/routes/) for a little more information.